# Exponential autocorrelation function by approximation of derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, correlation-functions

I have been pondering about the following question:

> Given a time-dependent function $f(t)$, is it possible to show that its autocorrelation function will generally follow a decaying exponential behavior for some time $\tau$, i.e. $\langle f(t)f(t+dt) \rangle_t \rightarrow e^{-dt/{\tau}}$?
>
> EDIT: assuming $f(t)$ varies and has an autocorrelation function independent of initial time

I was thinking about the following. To first order:

$$\dot{f}(t) \approx \frac{f(t+dt) - f(t)}{dt}$$

so
$$\frac{d}{dt}[f(t)f(t+dt)] - f(t)\dot{f(t+dt)} = \dot{f}(t) f(t+dt) \approx \frac{f(t+dt)^2 - f(t)f(t+dt)}{dt}$$

with
$$f(t) \dot{f(t+dt)} \approx f(t)\frac{f(t+2dt) - f(t+dt)}{dt} =  \frac{f(t)f(t+2dt) - f(t)f(t+dt)}{dt}$$

Assuming that the correlation with $t+2dt$ is approximately zero (first term in last equation), I obtain

$$\frac{d}{dt}[f(t)f(t+dt)] \approx \frac{f(t+dt)^2}{dt} - \frac{2}{dt}f(t)f(t+dt)$$

which kind of looks what I am trying to achieve. Are my approximations defensible? What about the $\frac{f(t+dt)^2}{dt}$ term? Or did I follow the wrong way?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what is $f(t)$? If not, the answer to your question is trivially 'no'. For example, pick $f(t) = 1$ and get $<f(t) f(t+dt)> = 1$.

Comment: I would try it for a general time-dependent function, that is $f(t) \neq f(t+dt)$, and assuming it is a function for which the autocorrelation does not depend on the initial time $t$ (i think of correlated noise). I want to prove that for any such function, one can find a time $\tau$ (it can be small) for which the autocorrelation is exponentially decaying.

Answer (score 1):

No. Witness the [Wiener-Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem). Arbitrary power spectral densities are possible and observable with physical processes. Accordingly, their Fourier transforms (*i.e.* autocorrelation functions) can also be pretty much arbitrary.

An exponential autocorrelation function is the special case when the power spectral density function is a Lorentzian function of spatial frequency:

$$H(f) \propto  \frac{1}{1+\frac{(f-f_0)^2}{f_B^2}}$$

Comment: I agree that the Lorentzian PSD will give an exponential decaying ACF, _for all dt_. My question is rather: can i find a $\tau$ (however small it is), for which some time varying function will decay exponentially on this small time scale.

Comment: @M.Hennes Well, one can always match any differentiable-with-time decay to exponential decay over a short enough time scale - just match the initial gradients.

Comment: Yes this is what i am trying to do. What do you mean by match the gradients? Are my calculations close?

Comment: @M.Hennes Well, $R(0)=\sigma^2$ and so, for small $t$, $R(t) = \sigma^2- R^\prime(0)\,t$. Also $\sigma^2\,\exp(-t/\tau)=\sigma^2-\sigma^2\,t/\tau+\cdots$, so just choose $\tau$ s.t. $R^\prime(0) = \sigma^2/\tau$. But it won't work if $Rˆ\prime(0)=0$: then you are going to need a Gaussian approximation.

Comment: But here you approximate the $exp$ by its first order linear term. So you show that for an _even smaller_ time, the ACF decays linearly in time, with constant slope $R'(0)$. My question relates to the full exp.

Comment: @M.Hennes then I don't believe your question is well posed yet. You need to do some more thinking about what approximation criterion you are grasping for. Globally the answer to your question is no, by Wiener Kinchin. Locally the answer is yes, if $R^\prime(0)$ exists and is nonzero. If $R^\prime(0)=0$, then Gaussian needed. So you clearly are thinking about an in-between criterion- what is this criterion?